# Does Fluent Migration work with .net core web api's?

Tags: asp.net-web-api, .net-core, fluent-migrator

I have worked with fluent migrations in the .net framework (with the class library). Can I use fluent migration with .net core as well, especially with **'.Net Core Web API's'**?

Comment: Can you elaborate how you want to use it?  I could see several different ways.

Comment: Just like we use it in .net framework using a class library and all the procedures. And it worked properly. But I tried to do the same thing with .net core but it didn't work.

Comment: I have seen several people suggesting they host FluentMigrator in a Web API project but nobody shows me how they exposed the endpoints. For example, why would you expose to your network ability to invoke Migrations to a random database?